# How do I get Local Database files to work in Visual Studio 2010 B2?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, local-database

In Visual Studio 2008 I can add a local database file (.sdf) and work with it just fine. In Visual Studio 2010 B2, I can add the file, but it doesn't get added to Server Explorer, and when I try double clicking on it I get this error:

> The operation could not be completed.
>   Unspecified error

Has anyone else gotten this error? Does anyone know how to fix it? Google isn't giving me much on this one.

**UPDATE:** I've gotten a new error message now. When I reinstalled SQL Server Compact Edition and then deleted  the sdf file and readded it, I get this message:

> The data provider required to connect
>   to the local data file could not be
>   found. The file will be added to the
>   project but the typed DataSet
>   associated with the file will not be
>   generated.

Comment: I know it does work as I've been using compact 3.5 sp1 with b2.  Never got that error tho.  I'd think about reinstalling Sql Server compact.

Comment: That is good to know. Now I know it's something worth chasing because I was thinking it might just be a B2 issue in general.

Answer (score 1):

I guess x64 users are out of luck, this doesn't work for me either. 
I tried everything, installing, removing, installing other versions of Visual studio (2008), updating sql compact edition, removing it, using the original version and again the sp1
No luck. 
If I install VS2008, it works perfectly.